# How to call a function only once in parameterized test case pytest?

Tags: python, testing, automated-tests, pytest

Im automating testing of a web application using PYTEST. I have multiple parameterized test cases. For example I am checking if data is created in db then I need to call data_entry function only once when the test starts. How can I achieve this using pytest?

Scenario:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "test_input,expected",
    [('ad', 'CREATED'), ('dn', 'CREATED')]
)
def test_case_1_entity_CREATED_verification(self, test_input, expected):
    dataenter();
```

How can I call this only once in my testcase?

Comment: You can write a session-scoped fixture that will call the function only once per test run.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Extract `dataenter()` as a fixture with scope `"session"`

Example:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def dataenter():
    # your code here

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "test_input, expected",
    [('ad', 'CREATED'), ('dn', 'CREATED')]
)
def test_case_1_entity_CREATED_verification(self, test_input, expected, dataenter):
    # your code here
```